# Electronic shifting for planetary gear hub

Tags: internally-geared-hub, shifting, electronics

Gear hubs are nice, but after getting a Rohloff I realized that shifting is extremely difficult and requires lots of effort. So this got me thinking: do electronic shifting systems exist for gear hubs? I know about Di2 for derailleurs, but what about geared hubs?

Comment: 'Rohloff...shifting is extremely difficult "  <-- that sounds like something's wrong, and fitting electric shifting is treating the symptom not the cause.

Comment: Rohloff hubs normally shift very easily. If the hub is new or fairly new it is still covered by the manufacturer's warranty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Rohloff](https://www.rohloff.de/en/company/news/news/rohloff-e-14/) has developed electronic shifting for their hub; Shimano offers an [electronic-shifting add-on for Alfine](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/city---comfort1/drivetrain/internal-geared-hubs/mu-s705.html). I'm not aware of any such from SRAM or Sturmey-Archer.

Comment: You can't forget, or maybe you'd want to if you bought one. The Trek Lime with Shimano 3 speed electronic and automatic rear hub.

Comment: I have to admit, I've never heard of that one @mikes